How to automatically scrape the following CSV
Page
On the page above if you click 'Download CSV' it will download a CSV file to your computer. I would like to set up a nightly process to download that CSV. I'm happy to scrape the data as well, a CSV just seems easier. I'm not really finding anything. Help?

import requests

def get_daily_stats(url):
    response = requests.get(url, headers={
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        'Referer': 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/custom?year=2024&type=batter&filter=&min=q&selections=pa%2Ck_percent%2Cbb_percent%2Cwoba%2Cxwoba%2Csweet_spot_percent%2Cbarrel_batted_rate%2Chard_hit_percent%2Cavg_best_speed%2Cavg_hyper_speed%2Cwhiff_percent%2Cswing_percent&chart=false&x=pa&y=pa&r=no&chartType=beeswarm&sort=xwoba&sortDir=desc'
    })
    with open('daily_stats.csv', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    return

def main():
    url = 'https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/custom?year=2024&type=batter&filter=&min=q&selections=pa%2Ck_percent%2Cbb_percent%2Cwoba%2Cxwoba%2Csweet_spot_percent%2Cbarrel_batted_rate%2Chard_hit_percent%2Cavg_best_speed%2Cavg_hyper_speed%2Cwhiff_percent%2Cswing_percent&chart=false&x=pa&y=pa&r=no&chartType=beeswarm&sort=xwoba&sortDir=desc&csv=true'
    get_daily_stats(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This will download the CSV for you and save it to daily_stats.csv in the folder that the script exists in.  You'll have to install requests too - python -m pip install requests.  How to do it nightly would be more a matter of what works best for you.  I mean, you could just run it every night, or is your goal to have a process on your computer that would auto-run it?
I suppose this will stop working in 2025, but you could just change the year in the URL at that point.

This did it. Thank you! Can I ask how you knew to put in %csv=true?

Opened up Chrome dev tools (F12), went to Network tab, clicked Download CSV, looked up the new request that popped up, and that was in the URL: https://i.imgur.com/ar4tcjD.png

Super helpful. Just trying to learn. Thank you so much!

No problem :-) web-scraping is a good tool to have, and it can certainly make life easier, from downloading episodes of TV shows to just getting info like this from sites without having to go through a UI.

You could honestly just automatically just change the URL too if it's the same base every year.

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

# URL of the webpage
url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/leaderboard/custom?year=2024&type=batter&filter=&min=q&selections=pa%2Ck_percent%2Cbb_percent%2Cwoba%2Cxwoba%2Csweet_spot_percent%2Cbarrel_batted_rate%2Chard_hit_percent%2Cavg_best_speed%2Cavg_hyper_speed%2Cwhiff_percent%2Cswing_percent&chart=false&x=pa&y=pa&r=no&chartType=beeswarm&sort=xwoba&sortDir=desc"

# Send a GET request to the webpage
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Find the link to the CSV file
    csv_link = soup.find('a', text='Download CSV')['href']
    
    # Download the CSV file
    csv_response = requests.get(csv_link)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if csv_response.status_code == 200:
        # Specify the directory to save the CSV file
        save_dir = "/path/to/save/directory"
        
        # Create the directory if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
            os.makedirs(save_dir)
        
        # Save the CSV file
        with open(os.path.join(save_dir, 'data.csv'), 'wb') as f:
            f.write(csv_response.content)
        
        print("CSV file downloaded successfully.")
    else:
        print("Failed to download CSV file.")
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve webpage.")


import requests
import datetime

def download_csv(url, filename):
  response = requests.get(url)
  if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print(f"CSV file downloaded successfully as {filename}")
else:
    print("Failed to download CSV file")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  # URL of the webpage where the CSV file is located
  csv_url = "https://example.com/download/csv"

  # Filename to save the CSV file as
  timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  csv_filename = f"data_{timestamp}.csv"  # You can customize the 
  filename as needed

  # Download the CSV file
  download_csv(csv_url, csv_filename)

This defines a function (download_csv) that takes a URL and a filename as input. It uses the requests library to fetch the content of the webpage and saves it to the specified 'filename' on your computer.
